# apache2 RewriteRule not working correctly (id=$id)

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

I want to redirect my nieuws.php?id=$id to /nieuws/.html

This is my nieuws.php script for testing:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    echo "Your ID: $id";
    exit();
} else {
    echo "No ID";
    exit();
}
?>
```

For that i have the following script in .htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^nieuws/([^/]*)\.html$ /nieuws.php?id=$1 [L]
```

When i open `http://localhost/nieuws/2.html` i get **No ID**

But, when i change the rule to:
`RewriteRule ^nieuws([^/]*)\.html$ /nieuws.php?id=$1 [L]` (without the "subdirectory") and open `http://localhost/nieuws2.html` it works, i get **Your ID: 2**

Any idea how i can add a "subdomain"?

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have `MultiViews` enabled.

Turn it off using this line on top of your `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^nieuws/([^.]+)\.html$ /nieuws.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Try code as entered above in my answer inside your DocumentRoot/.htacces